# Composer - "Skipped tag , invalid tag name"

Tags: php, git, composer-php

When I update my project with

```
php composer.phar update --verbose
```

I can read this:

> ```
> Reading composer.json of myVendorName/myPackageName (0.1)
> Importing tag 0.1 (0.1.0.0)
> Reading composer.json of myVendorName/myPackageName ()
> Skipped tag , invalid tag name
> ```

However, I checked myVendorName/myPackageName git repository and I just cannot find any tag like this, even named " " or anything. I've fetch --all and fetch --tags all my remotes too.

Here's my composer.json

```
// Root composer.json
{
    "require": {
        //...
        "myVendorName/myPackageName": "dev-master"
    },
    //....
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "..."
        },
    ]
}
```

And myVendorName/myPackageName's :

```
// myVendorName/myPackageName composer.json
{
    "name": "myVendorName/myPackageName",
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "master"
        }
    }
}
```

What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the release - posted issue and PR with fix here for VCS type git:

(I would add that I was able to reproduce this issue easily)

https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/1978

Comment: Thanks, hope the PR will be merged soon.

Comment: Finally merged. Thanks again.